# How to use a programatically-generated f-string

Tags: python, string, format, string-formatting, f-string

I have a nested list which always has the same number of columns per row, but the number of columns can vary depending on user input. I would like to nicely format the output into columns using string formatting. Example:

```
grid = [['parent', '', ''],
 ['child1', 'child2', '',],
 ['', 'grandchild1', 'grandchild2']]
```

If I hard-code the f-string formatting, it works fine:

```
for col1, col2, col3 in grid:
    print (f"{col1:<20}{col2:<20}{col3:<20}")
```

produces the desired result:

```
parent                                                      
child1              child2                                  
                    grandchild1         grandchild2
```

What I'm trying to do is programmatically build and then use the f-string. I can programmatically build the f-string:

```
f_string = ''
for col_index, col in enumerate(grid[0]):
    f_string += "{row[" + str(col_index) + "]:<20}"

for row in grid:
    print (f_string)
```

produces the desired f-string

```
f_string='{row[0]:<20}{row[1]:<20}{row[2]:<20}'
```

but I can't figure out how to use the built f-string.

What I have outputs the f-string itself, not the f-string applied to the data in `grid`:

```
{row[0]:<20}{row[1]:<20}{row[2]:<20}
{row[0]:<20}{row[1]:<20}{row[2]:<20}
{row[0]:<20}{row[1]:<20}{row[2]:<20}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the format method:

```
print(f_string.format(row=[1,2,3]))

1                   2                   3
```

In a loop:

```
for row in grid:
    print(f_string.format(row=row))
```

Comment: Thanks! The loop code produces the desired result.